selenium not finding the elements i want it to on forex factory
I can't seem to get the high impact news from forex factory, I need someone to check my code think I am coding it wrong somehow
this is my code
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Automatically install the correct version of ChromeDriver
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Provide the path to the ChromeDriver executable
chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\smart\Documents\chromedriver.exe'  # Ensure this is the correct path to chromedriver.exe

# Set up the Chrome driver service
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

# Initialize the WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Set an implicit wait of 10 seconds
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Open the Forex Factory calendar page for today
driver.get('https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?day=jun9.2024')

try:
    # Find all <tr> elements representing high impact news
    high_impact_news = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//span[@title='High Impact Expected' and contains(@class, 'icon--ff-impact-red')]]")

    # Process each high impact news element
    for element in high_impact_news_elements:
        # Extract information from the element as needed
        # Example: Get the event title
        event_title = element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "calendar__event-title").text
        print("Event Title:", event_title)
        # Example: Get the event date
        event_date = element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "date").text
        print("Event Date:", event_date)
        # Add more attributes or actions as required

   
    print(f"Found {len(high_impact_news)} high impact news events")

    if high_impact_news:
        print("High impact news found")

    if not high_impact_news:
        print("No high impact news found")
finally:
    # Close the browser
    driver.quit()

I ran it through chatgpt and added some of its recommendations, I also ran through a lot of youtube tutorials but I am expecting the code to print found 1 high impact news with the time when the news was launched on the page, I have not yet coded the time as I am still struggling to only get the news, this is the element I copied from forex factory where I think the high impact icon is located in the scripts of the page
<span title="High Impact Expected" class="icon icon--ff-impact-red"><span>
so when the red icon appears (high impact news) I want it to print that there is high impact news

There is a typo in for loop. high_impact_news_elements variable is not defined, check and change it to high_impact_news

This can be a little more complicated if you have multiple high impact events per day. See, for example, 18 June 2024. In this case the date and/or time will span multiple rows and you need to work a little harder to get those data.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Remote(
  "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
  options=options
)

driver.get('https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar?day=jun18.2024')

try:
    high_impact_news = high_impact_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//span[contains(@class, 'icon--ff-impact-red')]]")

    for row in high_impact_news:
        print("==================================================")
        date = row.find_element(By.XPATH, "preceding-sibling::tr[.//td[@rowspan]][1]//span[@class='date']").text
        title = row.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class='calendar__event-title']").text

        try:
            # Time in same row.
            time = row.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//td[@class='calendar__cell calendar__time']//span")
        except:
            # Time in spanning row.
            time = row.find_element(By.XPATH, "preceding-sibling::tr[.//td[@class='calendar__cell calendar__time']][1]//span[not(contains(@class, 'icon'))]")

        # Remove line break from date.
        date = date.replace("\n", " ")

        print(title)
        print(date)
        print(time.text)

    print(f"Found {len(high_impact_news)} high impact news events")

    if high_impact_news:
        print("High impact news found")
    else:
        print("No high impact news found")
finally:
    driver.quit()

 I'm using a remote Selenium driver, but you can revert to your setup for launching the browser.
Output:
==================================================
Cash Rate
Tue Jun 18
5:30am
==================================================
RBA Rate Statement
Tue Jun 18
5:30am
==================================================
Core Retail Sales m/m
Tue Jun 18
1:30pm
==================================================
Retail Sales m/m
Tue Jun 18
1:30pm
Found 4 high impact news events
High impact news found

It's also worth noting that if you want to extract these data from a weekly or monthly view then you will need to scroll down to ensure that all content visible, otherwise you'll just get the data above the fold.

hi again i have added my code to yours, but my chrome driver worked and opened the website and now I cannot get it to work this is my error chromedriver auto installer module not found added it to system path, tried to manually locate the exe file please check my driver in the link if it is correct my chrome is 126 version https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16bOI7W21hvvbdYwLL4FgBAbuEMLQM5Dy?usp=sharing

I am also on pycharm i installed auto installler in the terminal and also checked that It has been installed bt no luck I also uninstalled and reinstalled it

If ChromeDriver has stopped working then this appears to be another problem. My code above would not have interfered with your ChromeDriver.

I'd suggest abandoning chromedriver_autoinstaller. Just install ChomeDriver manually. Ensure that it's somewhere on your execution path. Since you appear to be on Windows this might be as simple as putting the executable into your Programs folder. It's important to ensure that Chrome and ChromeDriver have compatible versions.

If you still don't win with this approach then I'd strongly advise you to simply use a Selenium Docker image, which is what I do. This means that you don't need to worry about installing ChromeDriver at all since it's wrapped up in the Docker image.
